# Is it possible to prove the Taylor Series by mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, taylor-expansion

Originally we have:
$$\displaystyle f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}{(a)}}{n!} \cdot(x-a)^n$$
So I wonder if I can write it like this:
$$\displaystyle P_n(x)=\sum_{p=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(p)}{(a)}}{p!} \cdot(x-a)^p$$
Therefore, I must prove by induction that:
$$\displaystyle P_{n+1}(x)=\sum_{p=0}^{n+1} \frac{f^{(p)}{(a)}}{p!} \cdot(x-a)^p$$
However, should I include the rest of the series, or does this not change the inductive step...

Comment: Induction does not apply at "$n=\infty$".

Comment: "prove that" $p_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k$? You can't prove that, *it's the definition*! What you need to do is prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}|p_n(x)-f(x)|=0$ for suitable values of $x$! One way to do this is to - under some hypotheses - prove some error estimates for $|p_n(x)-f(x)| and maybe those can be inductive

Comment: You first have to make sure that you know what you actually want to prove. What are the premises, what are the conclusions? There are versions of Taylor's theorem that you can actually prove by induction, e.g. the integral form of the remainder.

Comment: By induction you can prove that your $P_{n}(x)$ is true for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but for any $n$ it is still a finite sum. Power series contains infinite sum, it can't be the same with any $P_{n}(x)$.